# Hadoop Book weather data scripting map through-out the directory

Tags: bash, file, hadoop, scripting, directory

I'm working through an example in the Hadoop book based off Apache Hadoop. I'm trying to run a scrip. The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for year in all/*
do
  echo -ne `basename $year .gz `"\t"
  gunzip -c $year | \
    awk '{ temp = substr($0, 88, 5) + 0;
            q = substr($0, 88, 5) + 0;
            if (temp !=9999 && q ~/[01459]/ && temp > max) max = temp }
          END {print max}'
done
```

The problem is the fourth line produces
* gzip :all.*.gz:No such file or directory when the script is run...

I'm new to Hadoop but I'm recognizing the script doesn't know where the data is located.

Do they have to be in the same directory file or what is it?
I'm going to try that plan in the meanwhile...

Comment: Could you please post what is your objective(good that you showed what are you running) but we need to know what you want to achieve, so that only we could try to help you in same.

Comment: The script loops through the compressed year files, first printing the year, and then processing each file using awk. The awk script extracts two fields from the data: the air temperature and the quality code.

How would this script go about locating the compressed year files?

where `echo -ne 'basename $year .gz '"\t"` is... how does this find the location in the directory of the compressed year file, a basic .gz file? Should it be in a specific location?